# Simples assignment of mass object properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object with a bunch of properties, say

```
{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:"hello", e:"world"}
```

and another one with subset of those properties

```
{a:4, b:5, c:6}
```

What would be the most streamlined way with the least amount of code to assign values of properties of the second object to the first? I know I can assign individual properties one by one, but is there a better, maybe ES6 way?

Comment: `Object.assign()` comes to mind: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of ES2018, you can use the [object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to do this:

```js
let obj1 = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:"hello", e:"world"};
let obj2 = {a:4, b:5, c:6};

obj1 = {...obj1, ...obj2};

console.log(obj1);
```

Note that this is very much new syntax, and is only supported by the most up to date browsers. No version of Edge, for example, supports it. You will need to transpile it for older browsers.

This assumes that you want the properties in `obj2` to override those in `obj1`. If you don't, change it to `obj1 = {...obj2, ...obj1};`.

Comment: won't this repeat properties twice? or it doesn't matter and later duplicates overwrite prior ones?

Comment: that generates a new object, which need an assignment to the old object.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Since ES2015, [the later key defined in an object literal overwrites any former keys of that name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Duplicate_property_names).

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), which assigns all properties of the second object to the first object.

```js
var object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: "hello", e: "world" },
    newValues = { a: 4, b: 5, c: 6 };
    
Object.assign(object, newValues);

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const obj = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);
console.log(obj); // {a:4, b:5, c:6, d:"hello", e:"world"}
console.log(obj1); // {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:"hello", e:"world"}
```

this solution create new object with no impact of obj1

```
const obj = Object.assign(obj1, obj2);
console.log(obj); // {a:4, b:5, c:6, d:"hello", e:"world"}
console.log(obj1); // {a:4, b:5, c:6, d:"hello", e:"world"}
```

this solution create new obj object and store reference to obj1

Answer (score -1):

Good afternoon

yes, there is a better way with es6 it's called Spread operator, if that's what you were looking for, rate me

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: let object = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:"hello", e:"world"};
let newvalue = {a:4, b:5, c:6};
object= {...object, ...newvalue}